# Find the fixed point of a recursive functional?

Tags: recursion, fixed-point

> A functional is a function which takes another function as a parameter.
>
> The fixed point of a function is an input such that
>
> ```
> F(x) = x
> ```
>
> Given an example functional,
>
> ```
> T(F,x,y) = if x = 0 return 0
>            else return y + F(x - 1,y)
> ```
>
> what is the fixed point of the functional?

The functional looks similar to a recursive implementation of `x * y` given the `if x = 0 return 0` and function call with `x - 1`, but I don't see where to go with this. To find a fixed point in a normal mathematical equation you'd just set `T(f,x,y) = f(x,y)` and solve, but given the format that doesn't really work. I can't see how the RHS can be simplified to allow that.

Comment: There is no fixed point of $T$: the inputs and outputs have different types.

Comment: What DW says is correct, but higher-order functions (functionals) *can* have fixed-points—they are themselves functions! See the y-combinator and others for examples. It’s also possible to use a (tail-recursive) functional to compute the fix-point of any function that has one, given an appropriate starting value and step function. Ex [Scala](https://github.com/benknoble/loner/blob/b7024d1754061c9f20871e7a969a2fe3d88d2700/src/main/scala/org/benknoble/Loner.scala#L47) and [Clojure](https://github.com/benknoble/formallang/blob/66b2ee56369dbcf3f1f1604af80b2ac03c2a5fd1/src/formallang/fix.clj#L3)

Comment: Also worth pointing out that most functionals do not have a single fixed point, so it's not correct to talk about "the" fixed point. The two most interesting fixed points of a functional, because they always exist and are unique, are the least fixed point, and the "optimal" fixed point. A given functional may not have a single "maximal" fixed point, and so the optimal fixed point is the greatest lower bound of all of the maximal fixed points.